# Google Translate V2

Tags: translate

I've used Google Translate for years with excellent results. Now, Google has deprecated my version and now employs Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.

The Nuget Install-Package Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 -Version 2.0.0 installs, but causes the dreaded yellow screen saying is can't find one thing after another, and also System.Net.Http version conflicts.  Manually edit Web and Machine configs, and on and on.

Also, Google samples reference things with undefined namespaces.  i have the Google credentials json file.

I really don't want to change Environment vars in a production environment.

Bottom line?  I'm in agreement with hundreds of folks saying that this is a nightmare.

With Nuget, it's usually easy to install, reference and run.  Not so here.  Google's primers on this are unnecessarily verbose and impossible, at least for me, to follow.  This should be Nuget, reference, code.

I think I'm up to about 100 folks with the same problem.  Aaaargh!

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out and while the instructions are all over the board, the process is not.

This is for C#.

You need an account at Google that enables Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.
Once enabled, you'll need a json credentials file.  Download it and save it.
The instructions show how to use the Package Manager Console to allow these to work.

In your translate class, add these:

```
using Google.Cloud.Translation.V2; //PM> Install-Package Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 -Version 2.0.0
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2; //PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 -Version 1.50.0.1869
```

Then this (the encoding can be whatever you need):

```
//usage:
var translated = TranslateText("en", "ar", "Happy Translating");

public string TranslateText(string srclang, string destlang, string trns)
{
  var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
  var client = TranslationClient.Create(GoogleCredential.FromFile(path to json credentials file));
  var result = client.TranslateText(
    text: trns,
    targetLanguage: destlang, // ar
    sourceLanguage: srclang, // en
    model: TranslationModel.Base);
    // or model: TranslationModel.NeuralMachineTranslation);
    return utf8.GetString(utf8.GetBytes(result.TranslatedText));
}
```

Result:  سعيد الترجمة